# Extract a column from a vector Column in a PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, vector, pyspark

I have a PySpark Dataframe that was created by `pyspark.ml.clustering.LDA`.  The `topicDistribution` column is a vector of n doubles.

```
+--------------------+
|   topicDistribution|
+--------------------+
|[0.93673575849807...|
|[0.31615978901762...|
|[0.33657712774309...|
|[0.30523697192979...|
+--------------------+
```

I want to create separate, (non-vector), double columns for each of the vector columns.  Ultimately, I'm trying to "**unwrap**" the vector so I can write the data to a CSV file.

I've tried multiple approaches.
**Approach 1** was to simply index into the column

```
for i in range(3): 
    df = df.withColumn("Col-" + str(i), df['topicDistribution'][i])
```

but this produces the error

```
AnalysisException: u"Can't extract value from topicDistribution#858;"
```

**Approach 2** tried to use a UDF, but as you can see, my UDF isn't passed a vector but a "pickle".  And I don't know what to do anything with that.

```
getTyp = udf(lambda arr: getType(arr,1), StringType())
for i in range(3): 
    df = df.withColumn("Col-" + str(i), getTyp(df['topicDistribution']))
```

which returns

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|   topicDistribution|               Col-0|               Col-1|               Col-2|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[0.93673577353151...|net.razorvine.pic...|net.razorvine.pic...|net.razorvine.pic...|
|[0.31615869274437...|net.razorvine.pic...|net.razorvine.pic...|net.razorvine.pic...|
|[0.33657583318666...|net.razorvine.pic...|net.razorvine.pic...|net.razorvine.pic...|
|[0.30523585516934...|net.razorvine.pic...|net.razorvine.pic...|net.razorvine.pic...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

**Approach 3** used VectorSlicer which came close, but the resulting columns are still vectors.

```
for i in range(3): 
    slicer = VectorSlicer(inputCol="topicDistribution", outputCol="Col-" + str(i), indices=[i])
    df = slicer.transform(df)
```

which produces the following.  Notice that each column is still a vector (surrounding []'s)

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|   topicDistribution|               Col-0|               Col-1|               Col-2|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[0.93673576108710...|[0.9367357610871071]|[0.03151327102122...|[0.03175096789167...|
|[0.31615848955402...|[0.31615848955402...|[0.3289336386324864]|[0.35490787181348...|
|[0.33657818512851...|[0.3365781851285112]|[0.32473902350327...|[0.3386827913682095]|
|[0.30523627602677...|[0.30523627602677...|[0.3426806504112193]|[0.3520830735620017]|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

There has to be a simple solution, but I'm stumped.